# C# solution design to display web content from a complex calculation?

Tags: c#, service, web, date-arithmetic

I need to process a complex calculation to generate a report and display as a webpage.  It has to be run periodically to recalculate the formula based on new input.

I have a few ideas:
1. Create a web service to process and cache the content and then create a web application to request the content via HTTP periodically.
2. Create a service to output a file periodically and then create a web application to read the file.
3. Create a web application which has a task in there running periodically to generate the output and then create a webpage to display it.

I have read some of the old threads but I want to know which is the better approach, the pros and cons or if there are a newer way of implementing this?

Comment: Try Pentaho, it is a very commonly used tool for ETL.

Answer (score 0):

JiTE!

I did a program that is similar to yours. The task is to generate a report when a user asks the application to do.  Usually it is a daily report, but the calculation costs several minutes, for there are too many records, and the fomular is complex, too.

We created a periodly thread to check wether it is time to calucate.Thus the thread will calute and store the condition and result into SqlServer. When users click the button to view the daily report, yet the report is in DB and the application just needs to read it out from DB, and show it on the screen.

Let disscuss your solutions: solution 1 and 2 seems good, but sulution 3 does not match the DesignPatterns, because all tasks are put in a single application.

Hope everything goes well!

```
                                                         David Liu
```